# Android wifi connectivity check

Tags: wi-fi, networking, connection-issues, network-signal

Windows OS has a functionality that checks internet connection periodically, if DNS resolution and traffic begins to fail it changes to "limited connectivity" and resets the WIFI drivers.

I know that android checks connectivity when it associates an AP to test if it's behind a captive portal (famous "gen_204" requests), but i can't find any meaningful information about evaluating the wifi connection 'on the fly' or even reset the drivers to 'unstuck' the supplicant and/or drivers.

Does android has any connectivity check 'on the fly' ?

Comment: Android does report via a [notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/184640/96277) when a wifi has no or loses internet access. You could have tried this yourself. If you have a router at home, just unplug its cable that brings it internet and see if Android later on detects this or not. // Also, it is frowned upon to ask the same question by making a new account. It is considered as circumventing site policies. Please don't do that. If your question gets closed for being unclear then you can edit it and make it clear, and then make a reopen flag request.